# Как вводить числа и строки, чтобы компьютер различал str это или int?

Tags: python

Нужно написать программу которая при вводе символов определит число это или нет и напишет "Это число" и "Это не число".
Input() по умолчанию считывает символы как str.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

вот пример:

```
user = input("ввод с клавиатуры: ")

try:
    int(user)
    print("число")
except ValueError:
    print("строка")
```

Comment: Теперь отрицательные целые числа у вас не числа. Было же почти нормально в прошлый раз (максимально универсально), только if не нужен.

Comment: хорошо, вот способ для всего и сразу

Comment: @MarkLiman, а откуда взялся `float`?  ОП спрашивал о целых числах (в заголовке).. :)

Comment: Теперь `nan` это тоже число)

Comment: Тут что, целый сквад тестеров образовался? Напишите свой рабочий вариант, а этот удовлетворяет все заданные требования

Comment: @MarkLiman есть такая штука как очередь проверки. А также каждая правка поднимает вопрос на главной странице, кто-то вполне может зайти посмотреть, почему это закрытый вопрос поднимается опять. Так что тут нечему особо удивляться.

Comment: @MarkLiman рабочий вариант уже есть в вопросе, на который данный вопрос закрыт дубликатом. В этом закрытом вопросе уже нельзя добавить ответы.

Comment: Мне уже начинает казаться, что вы меня булите, про целые числа, речи не шло, а этот вариант отличит и целые и с плавающей точкой ..

Comment: В смысле не шло, прямо в заголовке написано: "Как вводить числа и строки, чтобы компьютер различал str это или int?"

Comment: Хорошо, сам поменяю